# Elements of my spinner also dim when I dim the entire page for a loading element

Tags: css

I have implemented a loading spinning icon which is overlaid on the page.
It looks fine but when I try to darken the entire page by using

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

in the `.spinner-container` element, the bands of the loading element dim also...

See these pictures...

[image: Normal bright bands]

[image: Darker bands when container element is dimmed]

I would like to keep these bright vibrant colors on top of the dimmed gray background.

Any ideas what I can implement to change this?

```css
.spinner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

.three-dots span {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.spinner-sector {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

.spinner-text {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.spinner-sector-blue {
  animation: rotate 2s ease-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightblue;
}

.spinner-sector-red {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-in infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightcoral;
}

.spinner-sector-green {
  animation: rotate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightgreen;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="spinner-container">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="spinner-text three-dots">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
      <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-red"></div>
      <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-blue"></div>
      <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mix-blend-mode: overlay;` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)) on your `.spinner-sector` elements, which is blending the vibrant colours with the darkened page below.

Removing that gives you:

```css
.spinner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

.three-dots span {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.spinner-sector {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
}

.spinner-text {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.spinner-sector-blue {
  animation: rotate 2s ease-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightblue;
}

.spinner-sector-red {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-in infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightcoral;
}

.spinner-sector-green {
  animation: rotate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightgreen;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-container">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="spinner-text three-dots">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-red"></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-blue"></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, to keep the blending effect, you could switch to an option that doesn't darken the loading animation, e.g. `hard-light`

```css
.spinner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

.three-dots span {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.three-dots span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.spinner-sector {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.spinner-text {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.spinner-sector-blue {
  animation: rotate 2s ease-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightblue;
}

.spinner-sector-red {
  animation: rotate 2.5s ease-in infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightcoral;
}

.spinner-sector-green {
  animation: rotate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-top: 15px solid lightgreen;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-container">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="spinner-text three-dots">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-red"></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-blue"></div>
    <div class="spinner-sector spinner-sector-green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YES!  That does fix it... Only problem (I guess) is that that property was being used to blend the colors of the different bars when they met up in the circle... So when the two colors collided their colors would blend together to make more colors....  Can you think of any way to keep this functionality while also keeping the vibrant colors?  Thanks!

Comment: You'll see in the original example that there are a lot of additional colors.

Comment: @Tim Well, it's tough to get the exact same effect as "overlay", but you could get something similar by using one of the other `mix-blend-mode` options. E.g. `hard-light` gives you some very vibrant combinations. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: that looks beautiful!  Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: @Tim This isn't really what you were trying to achieve, but I also noticed that if you remove the `border: 15px solid transparent;` from `.spinner-sector` you get a very cool almost liquid-like effect.

Comment: That is indeed very beautiful.  Thanks for pointing that out!